# Call Dynamic Control's Event if exists

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The scenario:

I have some JSON data which I'm using to load stored-data into fields on my form. One of these fields is a DropDownList. The DropDownList happens to be in a child, of a child ASCX control, which I'm accessing from a parent ASPX page. When this DropDownList has its SelectedIndexChanged, it makes other fields visible on the form.

I'm using one of my functions to find this control, which is working successfully, but when setting the SelectedValue of my DropDownList control, the SelectedIndexChanged event is not firing. Meaning some fields aren't loading, resulting in some JSON data not being loaded and lost.

I have seen a suggestion of simply calling ddl_SelectedIndexChange(sender, args) function, but the page I'm calling dynamically loads hundreds of child controls depending on the current request, so was wondering if there is a way of invoking the SelectedIndexChanged event (if it exists) for a control, without having to search and manually call the ddl_SelectedIndexChanged() function. Is it possible?

```
DirectCast(WebUtils.ControlFinder(upMain, f.fieldClientID), DropDownList).SelectedValue = f.fieldData.ToUpper()
```

I hope it makes sense. Sorry if I haven't made this clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Reflection to Invoke the properties event that I required, worked a treat.